# Is there a way to fix the referrer: none for a 301 error?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-301, referrer

I'm relatively new to scrapy and I'm wondering if there is a way to pass a referrer to the response.follow() command. I'm trying to scrape real estate land prices from a hand full of the site and I'm having trouble getting scrapy to follow the pagination links. The scraper works fine on the main page, but the site won't allow it to access any of the other pages.

I tried to open up the 2nd page directly using the fetch command in the scrapy shell, but it didn't work. I opened the page using the view to inspect the element and found the following error:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://someaddress.com from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource."

any advice or resources would be really appreciated.

-Thanks

```
import scrapy


class cwSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cushman2'
    custom_settings = {
        'DUPEFILTER_DEBUG': 'True',
    }
    start_urls = ['https://cwstevenson.ca/properties/advance-search-properties/']
    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to author pages
        for href in response.css('.wpl_prp_bot a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_property)

        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def parse_property(self, response):
        response.request.headers.get('Referrer', None)
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).extract()

        yield {
            'address' : extract_with_css('h1.title_text::text'),
            'Prop_Type': extract_with_css('.ldetailscont2 p.ldetailsinfo::text')[0],
            'Land Area': extract_with_css('.ldetailscont2 p.ldetailsinfo::text')[1],
            'Price': extract_with_css('.ldetailscont2 p.ldetailsinfo::text')[2],
            'Listing_Type': extract_with_css('.ldetailscont2 p.ldetailsinfo::text')[3],
            'Area_Avail': extract_with_css('.ldetailscont2 p.ldetailsinfo::text')[4],
            'Prop_Taxes': extract_with_css('.ldetailscont2 p.ldetailsinfo::text')[5],
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract link as string otherwise it returns a list of `selector`s.
`response.follow` requires `url` as string. It doesn't accept list of `selector` objects.
as `response.follow` doesn't recieve valid arguments - it doesn't perform next requests

```
def parse(self, response):
    # follow links to author pages
    for href in response.css('.wpl_prp_bot a::attr(href)').extract():   #
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_property)

    # follow pagination links
    for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract():   #
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse)
```

Comment: This didn't see to fix the issue. After substantial googling and looking through the headers for the site I have found a solution for this particular problem. Please see my answer and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Use the header parameter in the .follow line you can pass any relevant information to the follow command to satisfy the sites headers. in this case it was the referrer.  To get an understanding of the sites header, you can open up your developer tab in chrome go to the network tab then to the XHR tab (make sure this is open when the site is loaded, if not just refresh the page once's it's open) click on the headers tab and scroll down until you see referrer under header portion. You can use this to populate the headers in your sprider. I believe there are options to do this through your middleware's, but none of the options seemed to satisfy the requirements of this problem.(ie: same_origin, origin...ect)

```
def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to author pages
        for href in response.css('.wpl_prp_bot a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_property, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/71.0.3578.98', "Referer": href})

        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse,headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/71.0.3578.98', "Referer": href})
```